# Universal property of 2-pullback

Tags: category-theory, universal-property, pullback, 2-categories

According to the [n-lab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-pullback) on 2-pullbacks,

> A 2-pullback in a 2-category is a square
> $$  \begin{array}{ccc}   
> P & \xrightarrow{p} & A \\\
> q\downarrow & & \downarrow{f}\\\  
> B & \xrightarrow{g} & C 
> \end{array}  $$
> which commutes up to isomorphism, and which is universal among such squares in a 2-categorical sense.
> This means that 
> (1) given any other such square
> $$  \begin{array}{ccc}   
> Z & \xrightarrow{v} & A \\\
> w\downarrow & & \downarrow{f}\\\  
> B & \xrightarrow{g} & C 
> \end{array}  $$
> which commutes up to isomorphism, there exists a morphism $u:Z→P$ and isomorphisms $pu≅v$ and $qu≅w$ which are coherent with the given ones above, and 
> (2) given any two morphisms $u,t:Z→P$ and 2-cells $α:pu→pt$ and $β:qu→qt$ such that $fα=gβ$ (modulo the given isomorphism $fp≅gq$), there exists a unique 2-cell $γ:u→t$ such that $pγ=α$ and $qγ=β$.

My question is, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are isomorphisms, does $\gamma$ also need to be an isomorphism? If not in general, are there some conditions on $p$ and $q$ (weaker than $p$ and $q$ being equivalences) that would make it true?
Specifically, I have a situation where $p$ has a left quasi-inverse, i.e. $sp\cong id$ for some $s$.

Comment: Yes. The point is that the category of morphisms $Z \to P$ is equivalent to a certain category whose objects and morohisms are as in the definition.

Comment: @ZhenLin thank you!